# CodeMirror Import text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have the following function using the CodeMirror.

```
function app() {
    jQuery.get('http://localhost:2748/foo.txt', function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    alert(data);
    editor.setValue(data);
}
```

The alert displays the textfile data but when I assign them to the editor are not displayed. If I for example I make a new variable `t = "test";` and then `editor.setValue(t);` then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` is not available outside the callback function. Set the editor value inside your callback:

```
function app() {
    jQuery.get('http://localhost:2748/foo.txt', function (data) {
        alert(data);
        editor.setValue(data);
    });
}
```